# How do I calculate the inverse Fourier transform of the delta function?

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing

In the context of single-pixel imaging, the following statement is given:

> *"A Fourier basis pattern
> $P_F (x,y) $
> can be obtained by applying an inverse Fourier transform $\delta_F (u, v, \phi)$to a delta function":*
> $$P_F (x,y) = \frac{1}{2} \left[ 1 +| F^{-1} \{\delta_F (u,v)\}|\right] \tag{1}$$
> where $F^{-1}\{\}$ denotes an inverse Fourier transform and
> $$\delta_F (u,v, \phi) = \begin{cases}
> e^{i\phi} & u=u_0\,\,\mathrm{and}\,\,v=v_0 \tag{2}\\ 0 &\mathrm{otherwise}.
> \end{cases}$$

**How do I calculate the inverse Fourier of a delta function as requested in (1)?**

A colleague has stated to me that the inverse Fourier transform of delta functions
at different positions can be calculated using eq. (3):

$$P_\phi (x,y) = \frac{1}{2} \text{real} \left[ 1 + F^{-1} \{\delta_F (u -u_0,v- v_0) e^{i\phi}\}\right] 
 \tag{3}$$

**Is this delta function any different from the one presented in the eq. (1)?**

**How does one calculate the Fourier inverse of a product of functions?**

---

> [1] Hadamard single-pixel imaging versus Fourier single-pixel imaging, Z. Zhang *et al*. [*Opt. Express* **25**, 19619-19639 ,(2017)](https://doi.org/10.1364/OE.25.019619)

Comment: I have a feeling this is supposed to be a discrete fourier transform. Is it?

Comment: I am not certain, as the purpose is to allow "any signal to be decomposed into a set of
orthogonal sinusoidal waveforms of different frequencies". To me this doesn't seem like the "converts a finite sequence of equally-spaced samples of a function into a same-length sequence of equally-spaced samples" needed to use for DFTs but I am not very knowledgeable in the area.

Comment: In the context of single-pixel imaging, how would you have continuous signals?

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense. I am still not sure I know how to answer this though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Dirac delta function $\delta(k-k_0)$ the inverse Fourier transform would simply be
$$ F^{-1}\{\delta(k-k_0)\} = \int \exp(i k x)\delta(k-k_0)\ \frac{\text{d}k}{2\pi} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \exp(i k_0 x) . $$
In other words, just substitute the Dirac delta function into the inverse Fourier transform integral and use the standard rule to evaluate integrals with Dirac delta functions in them.

For the 2-dimensional case, the integral becomes
$$ F^{-1}\{\delta(k_x-k_1,k_y-k_2)\} = \int \exp(i k_x x+i k_y y) \delta(k_x-k_1) \delta(k_y-k_2)\ \frac{\text{d}k_x}{2\pi}\ \frac{\text{d}k_y}{2\pi} . $$
I'm sure you can work out the result.

Comment: What difference would it make that this function is 2-dimensional? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I am aware that a 2D dirac function is the same as the product of two individual dirac functions, but will I simply need to do two different integrals, leaving the result as the product of such integrals?

Comment: @user7077252 A double integral is not the product of integrals, unless the argument is separable.  Here only part of the argument is separable (the 2-D dirac).  Use separability to bring one dimension of the Dirac outside the inner integral, evaluate the inner applying the dirac rule, then evaluate the output applying the dirac rule.